# Unable to access img within Div with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to access the SRC of an image using BeautifulSoup in Python.  Here's the way the image is nested:

```
<div class="artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b">
   <a class="artistAndEventInfo-48455a81" href="https://www.bandsintown.com/a/11985-perkele?came_from=257&amp;utm_medium=web&amp;utm_source=artist_event_page&amp;utm_campaign=artist">
       <img src="https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/fallbackImage.png" alt="">
       </a>
```

I've tried three methods.

1: The logic being I'm selecting the parent div of the image in question, and then the child img inside of it:

```
image = soup.select_one('[class^=artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b] img')
        print "band image", image
```

This prints "`none`".  (It should output SRC).

2: using more explicit nth of type method:

```
image = soup.select_one('[class^=artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b] :nth-of-type(1) img')
```

But the output is still "none".

3:  I've also tried to use Selenium:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class^=artistAndEventInfo-48455a81']")
```

Which gives me the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression //div[@class^=artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b']/img because of the following error:

SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//div[@class^=artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b']/img' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=74.0.3729.157)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Mac OS X 10.11.6 x86_64)
```

Why is my code not working in all of these cases?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an error with your xpath

```
//div[@class^=artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b']/img'
```

should be

```
//div[@class='artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b']/img'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the src of the image then you should use the below code with the corrected xpath.

```
print(driver.find_element_xpath("//div[@class='artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b']//img").get_attribute("src"))
```

And if you want to use your option 1 and 2 then make sure you get the attribute `src` as below.

```
print image['src']
```

Answer (score 0):

Using BeautifulSoup, you would do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = ''' <div class="artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b">
   <a class="artistAndEventInfo-48455a81" href="https://www.bandsintown.com/a/11985-perkele?came_from=257&amp;utm_medium=web&amp;utm_source=artist_event_page&amp;utm_campaign=artist">
       <img src="https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/fallbackImage.png" alt="">
       </a>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')

img = soup.find('img')

src = img['src']

print(src)
```

Answer (score 0):

It might possible that your div tag class attribute value is dynamic.Instead of using full class attribute value you can try that below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''<div class="artistAndEventInfo-7c13900b">
   <a class="artistAndEventInfo-48455a81" href="https://www.bandsintown.com/a/11985-perkele?came_from=257&amp;utm_medium=web&amp;utm_source=artist_event_page&amp;utm_campaign=artist">
       <img src="https://assets.bandsintown.com/images/fallbackImage.png" alt="">
       </a>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')
image = soup.select_one('div[class^=artistAndEventInfo-] img')
print(image['src'])
```